# How to use only what I require in bulma?

Tags: html, bulma

I am carrying out a project. I want to modify a select without js, so I wanted to use bulma. I managed to give the required styles. link bulma through the html link, but then notice that not only the select but also the body and the fonts were being modified, which I don't want and I don't know how to solve. thank you anyway. Sorry about the wording.

Comment: Have a Look into [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/), you need to download the source and have a sass knowledge